# What's wrong with this algorithm?

Tags: debugging, language-agnostic

This is an abstracted form of the bug that led me into the code that formed the basis of [my prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659117/whats-a-good-way-to-structure-variable-nested-loops).  It's obvious once you see it, but several professional programmers familiar with the original problem and original language looked over the code and overlooked the bug before we caught it (admittedly, in its native environment it was closer to three pages long).

**Please [obfuscate your responses](http://www.rot13.com/index.php) so latecomers can have some fun too.**

```
most_bang_for_buck_score = 0.0
most_bang_for_buck_order = []
for appetizer in appetizers
    total_cost     = appetizer.cost
    total_calories = appetizer.calories
    for salad in salads
        total_cost     = total_cost     + salad.cost
        total_calories = total_calories + salad.calories
        for entree in entrees
            total_cost     = total_cost     + entree.cost
            total_calories = total_calories + entree.calories
            for desert in deserts
                total_cost     = total_cost      + desert.cost
                total_calories = total_calories + desert.calories
                if total_calories/total_cost > most_bang_for_buck_score
                    most_bang_for_buck_score = total_calories/total_cost
                    most_bang_for_buck_order = [appetizer,salad,entree,desert]
 print "You'll get the most food energy for your money ordering ",most_bang_for_buck_order,"\n"
```

Comment: That bug isn't really that hard to see, I think. (Of course, it helps that you already said there's a bug.)

Comment: I was going to write in white text, but there isn't a way to set the text color here. Oh well, by the time I'd figured out how to obfuscate, two other people had said what I was going to say anyway.

Comment: That's what I thought (I'm the one who caught it) but it took me a while too.  Part of the reason I posted this is curiosity--the original was very cluttered, and before I ever saw the code I heard some detailed (incorrect) explanations of the problem.  I wondered how hard would it be to spot cold?

Comment: @mmyers -- the two so far disagree (at least the way I read them) so go ahead and post yours.

Comment: @MarkusQ: Seems to be a down-vote magnet :-/

Comment: Oops, my answer was wrong, should have read the code more carefully. Deleted it :)

Comment: seems a pretty obvious bug, at least in this simple form.

Comment: I'll agree with mmyers that it isn't hard to spot cold, if you know that there's a bug :]

Comment: @MarkusQ: Actually, I didn't read Princess's answer very closely. I just sort of assumed she agreed with Daniel L, like I did.

Comment: @I agree with mmyers that it's a lot easier to find a bug after it's already established that there is one.

Comment: @Bill: Yeah; "There's a bug" + Nested for loops very often equals "Fbzrguvat vfa'g orvat erfrg" (trying not to make the same mistake twice)

Comment: I'm watching the question closely and seeing an interesting pattern: 1) people saying the answer is obvious, 2) wrong answers popping up and being almost immediately deleted, 3) the question getting voted down.  What does that say about programmers's egos?

Comment: The two answers that have been sticking around for the last 10 minutes or so are correct.

Comment: @Markus: I'll admit that the very _first_ thing I thought (but didn't post) was that it was a unbracketed for loop/if problem (i.e. only the first line of each construct being executed) that was obfuscated by the tabbing!

Comment: +1, +reopen: there are plenty of other puzzle threads on this site, what's wrong with this one? If anything, its interesting and encourages critical thinking.

Comment: This is quite cool, I'd almost consider suggesting the ability to encrypt the answers to your question for a day on user voice with a clickable "decrypt" link or something. What do other think?

Comment: I like the encryption idea...

Comment: @Garry: You don't like my link-title technique? ;-]  I'll admit that for this kind of thing, a <obfuscate> tag would be handy...

Comment: It could be just that I'm in a bad mood - which I doubt - but I think obfuscating answers is just w@nk. Either a question belongs or it doesn't. Either an answer belongs or it doesn't. I voted to close the question, but for its masked answers. The question is harmless, but should be wiki IMHO

Comment: @Binary Worrier Bad mood seems plausible (no offense).  SO supports  multiple use cases; some people come here to get their homework done or have someone do their job.  Some come here to learn, to see how other people think, and to test their skills; these goals benefit from masked answers.

Comment: I am all against the obfuscated answers. Negates the entire purpose of making the knowledge available. vote--;

Comment: @Yuval A: I was about to disagree and say that I don't see a problem with it. But now that you mention it, how will Google find anything on this page? I suggest that within a few days (when no one is answering anymore), the answers should all be decrypted.

Comment: Personally I don't care Google finds out, just happy solving a puzzle. I wish there were more of these : )

Comment: This is why functional languages are great =). Don't have to worry about mutation like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**ROT13 (or hover on this link to see the non-obfuscated answer as a tooltip)**](http://www.rot13.com/index.php)

V qba'g guvax lbh'er erfrggvat gbgny_pbfg/gbgny_pnybevrf ba rnpu cnff. Lbh bhtug gb whfg or fhzzvat rirelguvat hc bapr va gur vaarezbfg ybbc.

Ol gur jnl lbh fnir gur beqre nf bar bs rnpu vgrz, V'z nffhzvat lbh'er bayl fhccbfrq gb or univat bar bs rnpu sbbq pngrtbel.

Comment: As for the second part, yes, only one of each.  It was less arbitrary in the actual code.

Answer (score 4):

Sbe rnpu vgrz (nccrgvmre, fnynq, ragerr, qrffreg) lbh'er nqqvat gur pbfg bs gur arj vgrz, ohg lbh'er abg fhogenpgvat bhg gur pbfg bs gur cerivbhf vgrz sebz gur fnzr pngrtbel.  Guvf jvyy pnhfr lbh gb fhz gur gbgny pbfg bs nyy vgrzf va nyy pngrtbevrf, vafgrnq bs nyy pbzovangvbaf.

[ROT13](http://www.rot13.com/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

Vf vg ernyyl guvf rnfl? Lbh'er abg erfrggvat gbgny_pbfg be gbgny_pnybevrf va rnpu ybbc vgrengvba.

V pna frr ubj gur oht jbhyq or uneq gb fcbg ol ybbxvat ng gur bhgchg, gubhtu. Gur engvb bs gur gjb inyhrf zvtug abg punatr zhpu rira nf gurve inyhrf terj ovttre.

[ROT13, hover to see non-obfuscated as tooltip](http://www.rot13.com/index.php)

Comment: Correct, and I think you've hit on another part of the reason it was overlooked: for many cases it worked, and for many others it produced plausible results (e.g. returned one of the three or four most optimal, but not _the_ optimal).  This led to complex theories before anyone _looked at the code_.

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer is clear from the other posts. I'm just going to use this space to do this in a functional language (Haskell), where this kind of bug doesn't happen.

Just getting the maximum score is easy, assuming lists of (cost, calorie) tuples:

```
let bang (cost, cal) = cal / cost
 in maximum [bang c1 + bang c2 + bang c3 + bang c4 | 
                                 c1 <- appetizers,
                                 c2 <- salads,
                                 c3 <- entrees,
                                 c4 <- deserts]
```

If you represent your data as tuples of (name, (cost, calorie)), then it's more annoying. The best way would be to define a maximum function that uses a "key" parameter, like in Python (there might be one already, but I don't know about it). Then, you would just do this:

```
maximumkey snd [([n1, n2, n3, n4], bang c1 + bang c2 + bang c3 + bang c4) | 
                      (n1, c1) <- appetizers,
                      (n2, c2) <- salads,
                      (n3, c3) <- entrees
                      (n4, c4) <- deserts]
```

---

To complete the solution. This is how (roughly) how `maximum` is defined:

```
maximum xs = foldl1 max xs
```

So `maximumkey` is:

```
maximumkey f xs = foldl1 (\(a,b) -> if (f a) > (f b) then a else b) xs
```

Note: This is a bit inefficient, since it calls 'f' more than once per element.

Answer (score 0):

V thrff nyy gur cebqhpgf fubhyq or grfgrq gbtrgure :

nccrgvmref*ragerrf*fnynqf*qrfregf = gbgny pbzcnevfbaf

jurernf urer vg frrzf yvxr gurer'f nyjnlf gur fnzr cebqhpg bs gur svefg vgrzf pbzcnerq gb rnpu bs gur qrfregf (v.r. 7 pbzcnevfbaf sbe 7 qrfregf). vfa'g vg ?

...znlor V whfg qba'g trg gur nofgenpgvba : )

ogj, guvf ebg13 fvgr vf terng : )

http://www.rot13.com/index.php

Comment: Not quite.  Gur ybbcf ner arfgrq (n yn clguba)

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure how one would calculate the number of calories in a desert, but I imagine it would be vanishingly small compared to its cost, particularly in today's economy, assuming an entire desert were for sale.
>
> Assuming `total_calories` and `total_cost` are some sort of integer data types, each `most_bang_for_buck_score` will be zero.
>
> I'm guessing the algorithm always prints the first element from each course.