# Nested Foreach loop

Tags: php

I am new to php. I have a foreach loop that checks for a ticket and outputs this ticket data into a google spreadsheet the other foreach loop stores the oldticket ids but i need to compare the new ticket id with the old ticket id array and if it exists delete it and add the new ticket data. Im having a problem comparing the old ticket id with the new 1 please advise on how this can be done. Thanks

```
  foreach ($result->tickets as $ticket)
  {
    // For each for old ticket id's
    foreach ($result->tickets as $oldticket)
    {
           $oldid = $oldticket->id;
    }

    $row = array
    (
          "Ticket ID" => $ticket->id,
          "Ticket Title" => $ticket->title,
          "Created On" => $month_created_on,
          "Solved On" => $solved_on ,
          "Status" => $ticket->status,
          "Time Spent" => $ticket->time_spent,
          "Assigned To" => $ticket->assigned_to->full_name,
          "Mojo Number" => $ticket->assigned_to->mojo_number 
      );

    if ($ticket->id ==  $oldid){
                $ss->deleteRow($row);
    }
    $ss->addRow($row);

    return $row;
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why are you looping twice through the exact same result set? Are you doing this in the original code too...?

Comment: At the moment, your loops make no sense. What is a new ticket, and what is an old ticket? Why do you only have one $result? Should you not have $new_ticket_result and $old_ticket_result? If you want to check if the current new ticket exists in old tickets array, then you should do the check inside the second for loop.

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257519/nested-foreach) might help you. You seem to be a bit confused as to how you should implement nested foreach's

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough one to answer because it's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Normally, a nested foreach looks like this:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $subKey => $subValue){

       //code here while still being able to access $key,$value from the top foreach

     }//foreach

     //code here what you want to do per lower level grouping, ie the second foreach

}//foreach
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
foreach ($result->tickets as $ticket)
{
    // For each for old ticket id's
    foreach ($ticket as $oldticket)
    {
        $oldid = $oldticket->id;
    }

    $row = array
    (
        "Ticket ID" => $ticket->id,
        "Ticket Title" => $ticket->title,
        "Created On" => $month_created_on,
        "Solved On" => $solved_on ,
        "Status" => $ticket->status,
        "Time Spent" => $ticket->time_spent,
        "Assigned To" => $ticket->assigned_to->full_name,
        "Mojo Number" => $ticket->assigned_to->mojo_number 
    );

    if ($ticket->id ==  $oldid){
        $ss->deleteRow($row);
    }
    $ss->addRow($row);

    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your code like this:

```
  foreach ($result->tickets as $ticket)
  {

    $row = array
    (
          "Ticket ID" => $ticket->id,
          "Ticket Title" => $ticket->title,
          "Created On" => $month_created_on,
          "Solved On" => $solved_on ,
          "Status" => $ticket->status,
          "Time Spent" => $ticket->time_spent,
          "Assigned To" => $ticket->assigned_to->full_name,
          "Mojo Number" => $ticket->assigned_to->mojo_number 
      );
    // For each for old ticket id's
    foreach ($result->tickets as $oldticket)
    {
        $oldid = $oldticket->id;

        if ($ticket->id ==  $oldid){
                $ss->deleteRow($row);
        }
    }
    $ss->addRow($row);

    return $row;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$aOld = array(); // array to save your old tickets.

foreach ($result->tickets as $ticket)
{
  $aRow = array(
      "Ticket ID" => $ticket->id,
      "Ticket Title" => $ticket->title,
      "Created On" => $month_created_on,
      "Solved On" => $solved_on ,
      "Status" => $ticket->status,
      "Time Spent" => $ticket->time_spent,
      "Assigned To" => $ticket->assigned_to->full_name,
      "Mojo Number" => $ticket->assigned_to->mojo_number 
  );
  if (in_array($ticket->id, $aOld)){ // if we had such id, so delete this row, else add it
    $ss->deleteRow($row);
  } else {
    $ss->addRow($row);
    $aOld[] = $ticket->id;
  }
//  return $row; Why this is here? 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep old ticket id values into one array.
And then use in_array() function like following:

```
//Compose old ticket group.
$old_tickets = array();

// Add an old ticket id into old ticket id group
$old_tickets[] = $old_ticket_id;

//When to fetched new ticket ids, inside of loop, check if ticket id is already existing $old_tickets

if(in_array($ticket_id, $old_tickets)) { 
    // Do something, remove a row process in your case.
}
```

Well, and I see this is same answer with Anton's one. :-)